# Bind datagrid to a table and display fields from parent tables

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, data-binding, dataset

What is the best strategy to bind the datagrid in the following scenario in WinForms application.
Let say, I have a strongly typed dataset with tables:

```
Table1 (T1_ID, T1_VALUE) <--* Table2 (T2_ID, T1_ID, T2_VALUE) <--* Table3(T3_ID, T2_ID, T3_VALUE)
```

I want to bind a datagrid to Table3, and display fields from Table2 and Table1, and have ability to filter, sort by all columns:

```
T3_VALUE | T2_VALUE | T1_VALUE
```

What is the common binding approach in such cases?

I see the following alternatives:

1. add calculated columns: 
   `Table2.T1_VALUE = PARENT(T2_T1).T1_VALUE` 
   `Table3.T2_VALUE = PARENT(T3_T2).T2_VALUE` 
   `Table3.T1_VALUE = PARENT(T3_T2).T1_VALUE` 
   where T2_T1, T3_T2 - relation names. 
    This seems to be the right way to go, but I am concerned by the polluting the clean data model with redundant calculated columns needed only for UI purposes (elsewhere in code I would still use `Table3Row.Table2Row.Table1Row.T1_VALUE`
2. Use Linq to query the dataset and get columns from different tables
   But in this case, the grid will not be able to write data to table3 and also sort.
3. Bind grid to Table3 and handle events that render the cells, and output the values from parent tables there. 
   The grid can write to Table3, but can't sort (I am using syncfusion grid, but I don't think it makes any difference)
4. Implement a View that could display data from multiple tables, and update the main table. I didn't dig in this direction, it's seems to be too complicated. Is it possible?

As I have pointed, using calculated columns solves all problems, and seems the most easy way to solve it. But maybe there is more elegant and correct approach.

Comment: `I want to bind a datagrid to Table3, and display fields from Table2 and Table1, and have ability to filter, sort by all columns:`  --> Create a View !!

Comment: This is mentioned in #4. I am not sure if it's possible at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Syncfusion GridGroupingControl, **UnboundFields** collection will assist you to get this requirement achieved easily. The Table3 can be bounded to the grid and the fields that are required to be referred from other 2 tables can be added as UnboundFields to GridGroupingControl. The values can be populated through handling **QueryValue** event.

```
//On Load of Windows Form
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.AddRange(new DataTable[] { dt1, dt2, dt3 }); //dt1, dt2 and dt3 are Table1, Table2 and Table3 respectively
this.gridGroupingControl1.DataSource = ds.Tables[2]; // Table3 bounded
this.gridGroupingControl1.TableDescriptor.UnboundFields.Add("T1_VALUE"); // column from Table1
this.gridGroupingControl1.TableDescriptor.UnboundFields.Add("T2_VALUE"); // column from Table2
this.gridGroupingControl1.QueryValue += new Syncfusion.Grouping.FieldValueEventHandler(gridGroupingControl1_QueryValue);
```

If you would like to allow saving the modified data in these fields at run time, **SaveValue** event can be handled in addition and the underlying data row can be set with the updated value(reverse of QueryValue event code).

```
//Method Invoked to populate unbound fields with respective values
void gridGroupingControl1_QueryValue(object sender, Syncfusion.Grouping.FieldValueEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Field.Name == "T1_VALUE")
      e.Value = dt1.Rows[e.Record.GetSourceIndex()][e.Field.Name];
   else if (e.Field.Name == "T2_VALUE")
      e.Value = dt2.Rows[e.Record.GetSourceIndex()][e.Field.Name];
}
```

These unbound fields also support sorting and filtering.

Comment: This is not exactly that I was looking for, but this may work.

Answer (score 0):

I often come at these things from an Object oriented perspective. I would create an object that has all of the properties you want and bind to a collection of those objects. If you want two way databinding you can use an ObservableCollection to allow the grid to pick up changes to the collection and implement IPropertyChanged on the object's properties. Generally the properties from table 1 and table 2 would be read only on the object.

Comment: I googled for alternative approaches, and found several implementations of BindingList, that support sorting and filtering.
But the question is what is the common approach. I just don't want to reinvent a bicycle.